# Code Editor - Must-Have features?

Tags: editor

*I've been coding for almost 18 years, and having migrated to Macs for the last year or so, it was inevitable to start thinking about writing a code editor from scratch - probably, just to try this thing out, or to make something that perfectly suits my needs.*

And I was wondering :

What are the absolute **MUST-HAVEs of a good code editor**? (by order of priority, if possible)
If we're talking about a not-so-conventional feature, could you give me an example of actual implementation of that particular feature? ("xxxxx" like in Notepad++ on Windows).
Looking forward to see your answers...

**Well, there is sometimes a thin line between what could be considered as an "Editor" and an "IDE", but let's just not exclude more... IDE-oriented ones...*

Comment: A way to select text and have it send to a terminal!

Answer (score 4):

In my honest opinion, the really great code editors have your basic features plus they are designed almost exclusively for a single language.  The more specific (and less generic) the editor is designed the better it will implement all of the tiny little details of Python or Java or C++...

- FAST (read ... faster than Netbeans or Eclipse, even if that means compromising features)
- Show line numbers all the time
- Syntax Highlighting
- Allow Tab Indent or spaces, allow representing tabs as any number of spaces.
- Document outline (what functions/classes are in this file?)
- Support multiple languages at once (php, html, javascript) in the same file.
- Mark lines / highlight lines (allow jumping to code segments / marked functions / classes)
- Auto-save periodically
- Save open-files / reopen to last open files
- Save historical versions of the edited file (optionally)
- Show hidden/special characters (A button that shows symbols over tabs, newlines, etc)
- Switch between *Nix, Mac, Windows file-formats.
- Indent multiple highlighted lines
- Writing the code highlighter as a stand-alone library that can be maintained independent of your application and is specific to that language.
- Writing the code highlighter so it's stupid fast (sparingly use regex)
- Automatic Indentation (when I hit the enter key and I'm indented four spaces you should optionally start the next line at the same indentation)
- Highlighting Keywords properly (like True, False, None in Python)
- Autocomplete (classes, functions, built-ins, etc) .. (but keep it fast ... driven by a Ternary Search Tree not some verbose XML data structure)
- Not attempting to perform syntax error checking on every key stroke (man that is annoying, and often really slow!)
- Scope Awareness (rarely seen, but the ability to prioritize name suggestions based on the current line's scope)
- Built-in Support for remote file systems (ftp, sftp)

Comment: Well, with 17 of your must-have features already implemented and a couple of others in my to-do list (the last 2 are the only ones actually NOT to be implemented), I hope I'm in the right track... :-) Btw, I do agree with your language-oriented approach of an editor, though I'm mostly aiming at something "all-in-one" (and customiseable via plugins for language-specific stuff)...

Comment: You are on the right track, I commend your efforts.  I actually believe that we need better code-editors myself... I asked this questions awhile ago - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56511/building-a-common-syntax-and-scoping-framework ... THE IDEA being that only 1 person needs to write the API for highlighting/parsing a single language - SHOULDN'T we be able to agree on the functionality around a single languages introspection !?!?!?!